# value not retriving in ms access query with date time

Tags: sql, ms-access, datetime

need to select the amount of given date which will be in between start date and end date

its working fine for me when i am using '2/27/2012' or '2/28/2012'

but for '2/29/2012' its not selecting the amount

```
select amount  from tblPricePeriod where cdate(2/1/2012) <=cdate('2/29/2012 12:00:00 AM') 
and  cdate(2/29/2012) >= cdate('2/29/2012 12:00:00 AM')
```

[image: tblpriceperiod]

Comment: Is that *exactly* what you have? `cdate(2/1/2012)` is the cast of the division of `2 / 1 / 2012` to a date which gives `00:01:26` (as there are no quotes) but that would result in FALSE for any of your candidate dates .. also you can use `#2/29/2012 12:00:00 AM#` instead of `cdate('2/29/2012 12:00:00 AM')`

Comment: There are no column references in that SQL statement, cdate is a conversion function but you have run it against a typed value, not a field in the table, this query won't mean anything, could you clarify the question please?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if this query might be close to what you want.

```
PARAMETERS WhichDate DateTime;
SELECT amount
FROM tblPricePeriod
WHERE
        [WhichDate] >= StartDate
    AND [WhichDate] <= EndDate;
```

If you don't want to do it as a parameter query, but create the query with a literal date value instead, try it like this ...

```
SELECT amount
FROM tblPricePeriod
WHERE
        #2012-02-29# >= StartDate
    AND #2012-02-29# <= EndDate;
```

Another option would be to use a BETWEEN expression in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT amount
FROM tblPricePeriod
WHERE #2012-02-29# BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate;
```

These suggestions assume StartDate and EndDate are both Date/Time data type.  If they are text data type, you can use that CDate() function to use their date equivalents in your query.

```
CDate(StartDate)
CDate(EndDate)
```

Also the situation can be more complicated if your StartDate and EndDate values include time components other than midnight.  You could however use the DateValue() function to cast those Date/Time values to midnight on the same date.

```
DateValue(StartDate)
DateValue(EndDate)
```

or

```
DateValue(CDate(StartDate))
DateValue(CDate(EndDate))
```